# What does `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` do?

Tags: sql-server

What does `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` do?

Answer (score 17):

[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259229(SQL.80).aspx)

> The SQL-92 standard requires that an equals (=) or not equal to (<>) comparison against a null value evaluates to FALSE.
>
> When `SET ANSI_NULLS` is **ON**, a SELECT statement using `WHERE column_name = NULL` returns zero rows even if there are null values in column_name. A SELECT statement using `WHERE column_name <> NULL` returns zero rows even if there are non-null values in column_name.
>
> When `SET ANSI_NULLS` is **OFF**, the Equals (=) and Not Equal To (<>) comparison operators do not follow the SQL-92 standard. A SELECT statement using `WHERE column_name = NULL` returns the rows with null values in column_name. A SELECT statement using `WHERE column_name <> NULL` returns the rows with non-null values in the column. In addition, a SELECT statement using `WHERE column_name <> XYZ_value` returns all rows that are not XYZ_value and that are not NULL.

Comment: The very first result in a Google search for SET ANSI NULLS ON. You'd think it'd be quicker to search for it than post a question here.

Comment: That's exactly how I found it myself. :D

Comment: This answer shouldn't be up-voted, until it's fixed - it shouldn't just link to the information, it should also quote it. Isn't it the point of SO?

Comment: I agree in principle, Paulius, and haven't up-voted it myself, but when someone asks a question that can be so well documented and easily found on Google, I dunno that it's necessary to duplicate the answer here.

Comment: @Matt: unless the resource linked to goes away.  Not likely in the case of MSDN, but in other cases maybe.  I usually try to write answers as stand-alone, and use links for further reading or as supportive documentation.

Comment: I see no reason why an informative post shouldn't be upvoted just because it's a link.

Comment: I'm not in it for points anyway, so whatever. This OP has been registered for a week and the only activity has been 5 no-brainer questions like this. Yes, I checked first. I was not inclined to give it any more effort than OP did.

Comment: @MattHamilton you've read the MSDN documentation? SO will often provide a succinct and readable explanation. MSDN will often provide a long and obtuse labyrinth of linked pages yielding little useful information.

Answer (score 11):

It changes the way `NULL`s behave. `NULL`s in ANSI yield things like

`NULL = NULL` -> false

`NULL <> NULL` -> false

With `ANSI_NULLS` off, (`NULL = NULL`) -> true.

Answer (score 2):

`SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` instructs the server to evaluate statements involving `NULL` using non-standard semantics.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;
SELECT CASE WHEN NULL = NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END; -- Evaluates to 1 (bad!)
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
SELECT CASE WHEN NULL = NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END; -- Evaluates to 0 (good!)
```

You should **never create new code** with with the non-standard semantics setting of `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` because:

- It is never necessary,
- For database queries to behave with the rich semantics that occur when `NULL` is treated differently from any other value (for instance in a `WHERE` clause), values compared with `NULL` should always return False / UNKNOWN,
- It makes code that is more difficult to maintain since developers might not realize it is using the nonstandard setting, or be confused by it, and
- [Microsoft has warned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql) that in a future version of SQL Server that the setting will cause an explicit error.

Comment: I'm not finding Microsoft's warning in the link you provided. Can you point me to it?

Answer (score 0):

When on then It don’t count the Null Values and return 0.

When this is on, any query that compares a value with a null returns a 0

Example:
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SELECT empname FROM emp1 WHERE phone=NULL

Explanation:
It will return nothing because SET ANSI_NULLS is ON.

Source:

http://www.xpode.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ArticleId=599

Thanks,

Rohit