# Where Clause 'drops' more rows than expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, where-clause, clause

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 query that was returning "hypothetically" 100 rows. I'm actually working with 7k - 8k rows.

The `Where` clause is something like this:

```
Where Col_a = 'Y'
  And Col_b = 'N'
  And Col_c = 'X'
```

and 25 of the rows had 'P' in `Col_d`.

I added:

```
And Col_d = 'P'
```

and the query returned the expected 25 rows.

Then I changed to

```
And Col_d <> 'P'
```

I expected to get 75 rows but I got only 50.

I thought adding "`And Col_d <> 'P'`" would only restrict the rows in which there is a `'P'` in `Col_d`.

Why is that not the case and how do I figure out what else is getting dropped when I say And `Col_d <> 'P'`?

As I said - I am actually working with larger numbers so it is not that easy to eyeball it.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Have some `Col_d` as value `null`?

Comment: `= 'P' and <> 'P'` would not take into account nulls

Comment: To picture how NULL works more easily, bear in mind that it does not mean "empty" or "no value", but actually "undefined" or "unknown", so you can't assure that unknown is or is not 'P', for example. For this reason cells with NULL don't match either condition. That's why you have to specifically use the `ISNULL()` function or `IS NULL` operator. In case you haven't seen it, check the accepted answer's last edit, regarding the *magic numbers*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comment, `null` is a [special case](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp) when it comes to comparisons.

Assume the following data.

```
id     someVal
----
0      null
1      1
2      2
```

With a query:

```
select id
from table
where someVal = 1
```

would return id `1`

```
select id
from table
where someVal <> 1
```

would return id `2`

```
select id
from table
where someVal is null
```

would return id `0`

```
select id
from table
where someVal is not null
```

would return both ids `1` and `2`.

If you wanted nulls to be "counted" as values in a = <> comparison, it needs to be cast to something like:

```
select id
from table
where isNull(someVal, -1) <> 1
```

returns `0` and `2`

Or you can change your [ANSI Null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/411868/2312877) setting.

> What I want to do is only exclude the rows that have 'P' in Col_d

So in your specific case, because you want to treat `null` in Col_D as a non `P` row, your query could look like this:

```
select * 
from someTable
Where Col_a = 'Y'
  And Col_b = 'N'
  And Col_c = 'X'
  And isNull(Col_D, 'someArbitraryValue') <> 'P'
```

You have to do the above, because as I pointed out throughout the answer and in the links `null` does not compare the same way as values.  You need to make the `null` something that is not null, (accomplished with `isNull(Col_D, 'someArbitraryValue')`) or change `ANSI NULL` setting in order to compare it as equal or not equal to some value.

Or as @Andrew pointed out [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) are bad (someArbitraryValue), so you could instead do:

```
select * 
from someTable
Where Col_a = 'Y'
  And Col_b = 'N'
  And Col_c = 'X'
  And (Col_D <> 'P' OR Col_D is null)
```

Normally I would do the directly above query, I was doing it the other way to mostly point out the differences in null comparison vs a value.

Comment: What I want to do is only exclude the rows that have 'P' in Col_d.

Comment: @Talay and in your requirement is `null` a non `P` row?  If that's the case when you would do `isNull(Col_d, 'someArbitraryValue') <> 'P'`

Comment: And yes - there are Nulls in that column. Sorry. I tried "and isnull(Col_d, 'NA') <> 'P' and that increased my resultset - but not by the exact number of rows . . . . Also, I still see 'NULL' in that column. I was expecting to see 'NA' ??-- Added this on 9/15/2015. R.S.

Comment: Sorry. I just re-ran the query and using - and isnull(Col_d, 'NA') <> 'P' - DOES return the exact number of rows I need. Thanks so much @kritner and

Comment: I usually try to avoid *magic numbers* that may be confusing. In this case I would do `And (Col_D <> 'P' Or Col_D Is Null)`.

Comment: er... previous comment should be @Andrew, not Answer.